# All the cold pressed virgin sunflower oil in shop is in transparent bottles. Does it mean it is already rancid?

Tags: oil

All the cold pressed virgin sunflower oil in shop is in transparent plastic bottles. Does it mean it is already rancid because of exposure to light?

Does it make any sense to purchase such oil now?

Comment: Direct sunlight may be a problem, not light in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the manufacturers and supermarkets are not in the business of exclusively selling rancid oil.

Sunflower oil has a shelf life of around two years. The turnaround time for oil is fairly high, so the bottles probably haven't been out on a relatively bright shelf for all that long. Check the use by date and as long as you have, say, a year to use the oil, it will almost certainly be fine.

Comment: I read on the internet that when the oil is exposed to light, it goes rancid. Can you explain for how much time can the oils be exposed to room light before they go rancid? You mean to say that if the oil is under use by date, then even if it is exposed to light it won't go rancid?

Comment: Assuming it has been stored reasonably normally as opposed to in strong sunlight, then yes, I would assume that it has not gone rancid before the use by date. The rancidification process is a slow one. Otherwise no one would sell, or buy, oil in clear plastic bottles.

Comment: The main issue here is what you do with it after purchase. If you leave it on your counter, exposed to bright light, in that transparent bottle, and it takes you a year to go through it, then it may well go rancid. But it's not instant; it still takes time, and it's not like leaving it out a few days, whether in the store or in your home, is going to ruin it.

Comment: Just  don't add water to it or feed it after midnight.